# Rails / STI - How do I show a different form based on the type?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form, sti

There are 3 different types inheriting from the same model. Each has one unique attribute that is irrelevant to the others.

If there is a link for each type, is there a way to use the same form, but dynamically show the relevant fields for each type?

Or do I have to create a different form for each and use a hidden field to tell the controller which type to create?

Comment: it is a good practice to show what your form looks like.

Comment: Er, I haven't actually created it yet. Hang on!

Comment: its also good practice to try something out and then ask for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you are passing a variable in the query string based on what hidden field you want to show

if this is the case this is what I would do

```
= simple_form_for(@model, :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal' }) do |f|
  ...
  - if params[:what_hiddind_filld_to_show] == 'type1'
    = f.input :fild_name, as: :hidden, , input_html: { value: '1' }
  - elsif params[:what_hiddind_filld_to_show] == 'type2'
    = f.input :fild_name, as: :hidden, , input_html: { value: '2' }
  - elsif params[:what_hiddind_filld_to_show] == 'type3'
    = f.input :fild_name, as: :hidden, , input_html: { value: '3' }
  - else
    = f.input :fild_name, as: :hidden, , input_html: { value: 'default' }
```

I hope this puts you in the right track

Comment: Thank you! I actually didn't know that something like this was possible, despite all my googling!

Comment: I'm almost in agreement with the answer, except that I would refactor 'type1', 'type2' and 'type3' to be instance variables in your controller which your form accesses. This will help make your code more extensible, especially if you are doing some manipulations in your controller too.

Comment: @RPV I would agree they are bad variables what I have no idea what they should be.